# Why topic.html doesn't work

Tags: django-templates

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p> Add a new topic:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">add topic</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I had topics.html, but I don't know why it does not render as expected.
I had a result page like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: And what do you see with "view source" in the browser?

Comment: It's actually "GET /new_topics/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the source; that's a http response header, and from the 500 I think it's even a server error. Which is different than before. 
 Are you running with the development server and `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: I changed the setting.py in which DEBUG=False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'].

Comment: If you want to debug your problem, you should `DEBUG=True` and use the development server locally to trace the error.

Comment: According to you, I nailed it. Turns out that the context should be a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Note that we had *no* indication the context was a list in the first place, since you never provided the view function, just the template.

Comment: Can you post your view? My first guess would be that you don't pass `form` to your template.